# How to sort list of locations according to driving list on one trip route?

Tags: android, google-maps

My Android app scenario is the following:

The user is a bus driver and he has some people to deliver to their locations(places). Is there is a way to do the following:

1. Get the best route passes from their locations.
2. Sort this list according to driving distance on that route.
3. Get each location's driving distance according to that route.

Can any of the Google APIs help me accomplish the above? Or perhaps a combination of two APIs?

**Update:**

I see that google-matrix-API give me the driving distance from an origin location to some destinations but I am not sure that it will calculate them as on the one driving trip.

Comment: You are missing some details in your question.

Comment: @LajosArpad what is the details you need to know

Comment: "this list of locations", "that route". No code, no attempt, asking for a product and so on...

Comment: @LajosArpad there is no code, I am asking how to do that.

Comment: By simple words I can, I have some locations I need go to each one of them in one trip by best route.

Comment: Tefa, the fact that there is no code means that you did not try anything, you did not put any effort into solving this problem and ask us to do a favor. You need to try to solve it, come back and tell us where did you fail and how. Or come back and tell us you had a great success.

Comment: @LajosArpad I was asking of how to do that? Asking on the idea or the way. Anyway thank you :)

Comment: Tefa, you could do that by using a modified version of Dijkstra's algorithm, but calculating all paths length and ordering the result. But since you do not give us any example of an input, nor any effort into solving your problem why should we work out the solution for you? Also, you are asking for tools which is off-topic here. I am actually trying to let you know that your question in this moment is of very low quality and I intend to let you repair it instead of just down-voting and voting to close. However, I start to think that should have been done from the start...